# Using treant with svelte

Tags: npm, dependencies, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to use the treant tree-drawing library with svelte. Here's as far as I got - I'm ok with basic svelte and JS/TS as well as web dev, but I seem to be missing a key bit of info how things fit together.

According to https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/, I need to include `Treant.css`, `vendor/raphael.js` and `Treant.min.js`. I also need to give each element where I want to mount a tree a unique ID. This all works fine if I just hand-code into HTML/JS files.

So, I want to make a `<TreeComponent>` in svelte. Steps so far:

- `npm create svelte@latest`
- type 'skeleton project' and 'js' to make things easier for now; cd to the folder
- `npm install uuid` for the ids (probably overkill, but should definitely work)
- `npm install treant`
- `npm install`
- `npm run dev`

In the main `+page.svelte` I change the contents to this:

```html
<script>
    import TreeComponent from "$lib/TreeComponent.svelte";
    const data = {
        text: "a",
        children: [
            {text: "b"},
            {text: "c"}
        ]
    }
</script>
<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>

<TreeComponent {data}/>
```

and create `lib/TreeComponent.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    import {v4 as uuid_v4} from 'uuid'
    // import {treant} from 'treant'
    export let data
    let id = uuid_v4()
</script>

<div {id}></div>
```

VS code moans at me about the uuid import line:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'uuid'. 'c:/Users/******/Downloads/treant-mwe/node_modules/uuid/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm i --save-dev @types/uuid` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'uuid';` js(7016)

Do I need to do something about this? It renders the component with a unique ID just fine when I check in the browser. But I like my stuff to compile without warnings.

The real problem though is that if I uncomment the treant line, it crashes with

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\******\Downloads\treant-mwe\node_modules\treant\src\Internals.js:12:9)       
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\******\Downloads\treant-mwe\node_modules\treant\src\register.js:3:17)        
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
```

I presume this is because treant tries to access `window` when you initialise it, as opposed to when you call it (`new Treant(...)`). Does that mean this library doesn't work with svelte's server-side rendering, as I can't even import the thing to later call it in an `onMount`? Or am I getting something more basic wrong here?

I also note that in the `node-modules/treant` subfolder, there's no `Treant.css` nor a minified version of the js file. Do I need an extra build/install step here, or something else? I also can't seem to find the `raphael` dependency, even though I did an `npm install`.

EDIT: in case you're wondering, I haven't tried to create the actual tree in this minimal example yet, because I'm still stuck at loading the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean this library doesn't work with svelte's server-side rendering, as I can't even import the thing to later call it in an `onMount`?

The file mentioned in this error has this bit of code at the top level:

```js
var defaultEventDefinition = {
  detail: null,
  view: window, // <--
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
}
```

So yes, this will not be compatible with SSR, you can either [turn it off](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr) or do a dynamic `import()` in `onMount` to work around the problem.

---

The `uuid` import issue can be fixed by just following the suggestion of installing `@types/uuid`.

Comment: Thanks - I think I'm one step away from marking this as accepted, do you know if I need to do anything to pull in the Treant css/raphael.js files? I've turned SSR off as I'm building something that has to run off a static server anyway.

Comment: CSS can be imported either in the `<script>` or `<style>`, Vite should take care of including it, though imports in the `<style>` may end up being scoped ([see docs Vite docs for examples](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features#css)). If `raphael` is a dependency, you would need to make sure that is loaded before or at the same time as Treant (depending on whether Treant directly accesses it or only upon using `new Treant(...)`). Scripts can also be [imported as asset urls](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#explicit-url-imports), then those could be inserted in `<svelte:head>` or a `<script>`.

Comment: When adding additional `<script>` tags, making sure that everything is loaded can be a bit more tricky. So loading everything via dynamic import might be the easiest (they can just be awaited).